# Nestjs multer upload file after some codes

Tags: nestjs, multer

I am developing an api based on nestjs. I used multer package to upload file. The code sample on nestjs documentation is at the following:

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>) {
  console.log(files);
}
```

But I want to save uploaded file after send mail. If the mail sends successfully then I will save the file. If sending mail process is fail, I ignore the file uploding.
How can I figure out?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two ways, One is to create another route like`@Post('mail')` then depending on the response you receive in your client, let's say it returns an OK you can send another request to upload the files, or you can send both the requests to your API at the same time then cancel uploading the files (supposing this request takes longer to complete) if sending the mail was not successful (for this you need to handle errors that might result in incomplete files in your API, basically your API should know the full size of the files to expect so that you can compare if there was no cancellation).
The other way is using one route to do both of the tasks, in your example add the code for handling sending the mail and based on the condition that it went successfully do or don't proceed with uploading the files.